# Conformal Killing fields on Schwarzschild

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, vector-fields

I am trying to understand which are the conformal Killing Fields on the Schwarzschild spacetime.
I say that $X$ is a conformal Killing field on $S$ ($S$ is Schwarzschild) if there exists a function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_X g = fg,
\end{equation}
where $g$ is the Schwarzschild metric, and $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lie derivative.

I know that the time translation, $\partial_t$, and the rotations, $\Omega_{ij}$ are Killing fields, therefore conformal Killing fields, with $f$ constant and equal to $0$.

In the Minkowski spacetime, for example, parametrized by $(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3)$, I know that the ``dilation'' field, i.e. the field
$$
\sum_{i=0}^3 x^\lambda \partial_{x^\lambda}
$$
is a conformal Killing field, with $f=2$. I would like to understand if there is an analogous in Schwarzschild.

Answer (score 1):

In the Schwarzschild geometry, the Schwarzschild radius breaks naive dilation symmetry. In the simple case of a radial dilation $r \to \lambda r$, the geometry is only preserved by $R_S \to \lambda R_S$. So, it naively seems like it would be difficult to find a working dilation, even just a radial dilation.

I went to some effort (as an exercise for myself) to find a working dilation, and failed. What I have found is that the vector field

$$
X = t \partial_t + r \sqrt{1-\frac{R_S}{r}} \, \partial_r
$$

which approaches $0$ as $r \to R_S$ and $r \partial_r$ as $r \to \infty$ is *almost* a conformal Killing field. However, the lie derivative of the metric is

$$
\mathcal{L}_X g = 2 \sqrt{1-\frac{R_S}{r}} \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
-\sqrt{1-\frac{R_S}{r}}- \frac{R_S}{2r} & & & \\
& \left( 1 - \frac{R_S}{r} \right)^{-1} & & \\
& & r^2 & \\
& & & r^2 \sin^2 \theta
\end{array} \right)
$$

So, the tt component of the metric spoils everything. I spend a small amount of effort trying to modify this vector field (adding it a timelike component, adding in explicit time dependence, etc.), but so far nothing has worked.